# Contour Integral of $1/(x^2+1)^{3/2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-points

If I want to find the contour integral of
$$ \oint_{|x-i|=\rho} \frac{1}{(x^2+1) \sqrt{ x^2+1}} dx  $$
where
$$ \rho \rightarrow 0 $$
How can I do that? Is there any useful approximation I can used for this integral so that the residue theorem can be applied? I have tried the generalized binomial theorem, but it seems that it dose not work.

Comment: The function can not well defined as a holomorphic function on those circles. There needs to be a branch cut which will pass through the circles.

Comment: If you set $x = i + \epsilon\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$, you get ${1 \over \left(\,x^{2} + 1\,\right)\,\sqrt{\,x^{2} + 1\,}\,}\,  \stackrel{\mathrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim} \epsilon^{-3/2}\,\mathrm{e}^{-3\,\mathrm{i}\theta/2}$ and $\,\mathrm{d}x \propto \epsilon\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ such that your integral is $\propto {1 \over \sqrt{\epsilon}} \times \left(\,\mbox{a non null factor}\,\right)$. Jack already found that it diverges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=z+i$, then
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{\rho\to0}\int_{|x-i|=\rho}\frac1{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\rho\to0}\int_{|z|=\rho}\frac1{(z^2+2iz)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\lim_{\rho\to0}\int_{|z|=\rho}\frac1{z^{3/2}}\frac1{(z+2i)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{-1-i}4\lim_{\rho\to0}\int_{|z|=\rho}\frac1{z^{3/2}}\left(1+O(z)\right)\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{-1-i}4\int_{|z|=1}\frac1{z^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}z\lim_{\rho\to0}\rho^{-1/2}+\lim_{\rho\to0}O\!\left(\rho^{1/2}\right)\int_{|z|=1}\frac1{z^{1/2}}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
\end{align}
$$
If we put the branch cut along $\operatorname{Im}(z)=0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(z)\gt0$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1}\frac1{z^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\int_0^1e^{-3\pi it}\,\mathrm{d}e^{2\pi it}\\
&=2\pi i\int_0^1e^{-\pi it}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=2\left(1-e^{-\pi i}\right)\\[6pt]
&=4
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\rho\to0}\int_{|x-i|=\rho}\frac1{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=(-1-i)\lim_{\rho\to0}\rho^{-1/2}
\end{align}
$$
which diverges. This diverges no matter where the branch cut is.

Comment: My idea is shown and the result is -2 instead of divergence. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did, but I am not sure whether it's correct or not. First, I draw a contour with a branch cut as shown below.[image]

Based on the residue theorem,
$$ \oint_C\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}dx = \int_{C_R} + \int_{C_\rho} +\int_{L_1} +\int_{L_2} +\int_{L_3} = 0 $$

$C_R$:
$  Z=Re^{i\theta} $
$$  \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{iRe^{i\theta}}{(R^2e^{i2\theta}+1)^{3/2}} d\theta <\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{R}{\vert (R^2e^{i2\theta}+1)^{3/2} \vert} d\theta =0$$

$L_1$: 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}dx = 2$$

$L_2$: $ Z = Re^{-i3\pi/2}, R:1\sim \infty$
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-i3\pi/2}}{(R^2e^{-i3\pi}+1)^{3/2}} dR = \int_1^\infty \frac{i}{(1-R^2)^{3/2}}dR$$

$L_3$: $ Z = Re^{i\pi/2}, R:\infty\sim 1$
$$ \int^1_\infty \frac{e^{i\pi/2}}{(R^2e^{i\pi}+1)^{3/2}} dR = \int^1_\infty \frac{i}{(1-R^2)^{3/2}}dR$$

Then, $$ \int_{L_2}+\int_{L_3} = 0$$
Therefore,
$$ \lim_{\rho \rightarrow0}\oint_{|x-i|=\rho}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}dx =-2 $$

Is my idea correct? If not, please tell me why please.

Comment: $L_2$ and $L_3$ don't cancel because of the branch cut between them. Actually they reinforce and both diverge as $\rho\to0$.